# scrollview that has listview as a child is not scrollable

Tags: android

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layout_guide_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_guideTab_backButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backicon_round"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_guideTab_detail_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                android:text="Error"
                android:textSize="19dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_guideTab_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The ScrollView has a button and text for title and the rest is for a listview

What I want to do is to scroll the whole screen (including the relativeLayout above the listview) 
But the problem is that, when I try to scroll the screen, I can only scroll the listview...

Comment: Check out this simple library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1919

Comment: use `RecyclerView` with `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do use your scrollview using the following method.

```
public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView) {
    ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
    if (mListAdapter == null) {
        // when adapter is null
        return;
    }
    int height = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
        //no idea why this conditions are [no reference, just got from debug]
        if (desiredWidth == 0) {
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        } else {
            listItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        }
        height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    mListView.requestLayout();
}
```

Finally, you just have to call this function after you have added the data into the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have match parent for both the ScrollView and the LinearLayout. The height of the LinearLayout is really only 55dp plus the height of the ListView. So there's really nothing to scroll in the ScrollView. You can scroll the list because it itself can scroll as deep as necessary.

Do you see what I mean? Try setting the width on the ListView to something thin, then also make the height of the ScrollView really high and then try it. That way you can touch on the sides of the ScrollView to scroll the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

It is not suggested to nest ListView into ScrollView. You can add a head view as title for ListView, of course, you can simple use RecycleView.